# Помощь с запросом sql - поиск строки

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем привет!
Мне нужно сделать запрос: Найти предприятие, у которого больше всего вакансий.
У меня есть таблица в которой есть 5 вакансий, и есть предприятия которие дают ети вакансии. Но есть предприятие которое дало две вакансии. Одним словом надо сделать запрос что би найти предприятие у которого больше всего вакансий.

```
select nazva_pidpryemstva, COUNT(nazva_pidpryemstva) as KilkistVakansiy 
from Vakansia 
group by nazva_pidpryemstva 
having COUNT(nazva_pidpryemstva) > 1;
```

Ето мой запрос, но он рабоет не совсем коректно. Может кто то может помочь с етим запросом?

Comment: *Найти предприятие, у которого больше всего вакансий.* Сгруппировать по предприятию. Посчитать количество вакансий. Отсортировать по убыванию этого количества. Взять первую запись.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А если будет несколько компаний в которих будет несколько вакансий? По вашей схеме оно постоянно будет виводить только одно предприятие, а мне нужно что би виводило все предприятия у которих больше всего вакансий

Comment: Не я написал "Найти предприяти**Е**, у которого больше всего вакансий." Тогда ранжирование по количеству в CTE и вывод всех записей с rank=1.

Comment: Я только начал изучать sql, по етому ничего не понял со второго вашего коментария, буду разбираться, спасибо!
Еще простите за мой кривой руский, я не из России, и у меня нету русской розкладки, по етому пишу с огромним количеством ошибок

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH
cte AS ( SELECT nazva_pidpryemstva, 
                COUNT(*) cnt, 
                RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rnk
         FROM Vakansia 
         GROUP BY nazva_pidpryemstva )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь, сейчас буду разбираться)